# can someone help me to figure out how to remove the segmentation fault from hackerrank from my code

Tags: c++

Its not working and i don't know why:

```
int main() {
    int n,q,sizee,i,j;
    int ans;
    int ar[100];
    cin>>n;
    cin>>q;
    int **arr= new int *[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {  
        cin>>sizee;
        arr[i] = new int[sizee];
        for(int j=0;j<sizee;j++)
            cin>>arr[i][j];
    }
    i=0;
    for(int z=0;z<q;z++)
    {
         int x,y;
         cin>>x;
         cin>>y;
         ar[i]=arr[x-1][y-1];
         i++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
         cout<<ar[i];
    delete[] arr[i];
    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

it's showing segmentation error even though its working correctly in codeblocks.

Comment: Run in a debugger, try some different cases with different input, see if any indexing goes out of bounds. [*Undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which is probably what you have) have a nasty habit of working sometimes and the next crashing or worse.

Comment: Examples you need to look out for: `q` being larger than `n`, or `x` being zero, or `x` being larger than `n`, or `y` being larger than `sizee`, or `q` being equal to or larger than `100`, `delete[] arr[i]` possibly being out of bounds (and happening only for a *single* index `i` so you have a memory leak), and probably much more.

Comment: Skip all the manual memory management with `int **` and simply use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.  That alone would cut out half of what you've written, plus would be safer to use.

Comment: I'm surprised it compiles at all.  It is missing `#include <iostream>` and missing `using std::cin;` and missing `using std::cout;`.

Comment: Where is your error checking??

Comment: @Eljay AFAIK, Hackerrank already gives you the basic template. You just need to type in bits that the question asks for.

Comment: This code is hardly readable.  Try put some effort in making your code readable by giving better variable names and correct spacing.

Comment: @AdityaPrakash • could be; I'm not familiar with Hackerrank.  This isn't a Hackerrank forum.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
     cout<<ar[i];
delete[] arr[i];
delete[] arr;
```

is missing some brackets:

```
for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
{
     cout<<ar[i];
     delete[] arr[i];
}
delete[] arr;
```

`delete[] arr[i];` could give you a segfault for `i == q`, and maybe you should be looping with `i < n`.